# Add only one "Re: " to message subject on a reply

Tags: php, wordpress, email, message, title

I use a Private Message script where it adds a `Re:` to the message subject upon every reply. Unfortunately, if there are more than one reply to the same message, it adds another `Re:`, so by the time a few PMs have been exchanged, it looks like this:

`Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Hello World!`

Here are the relevant parts of the script that does this:

```
                    | <a class="reply"
                    href="<?php echo wp_nonce_url( "?page=rwpm_send&recipient=$msg->sender&id=$msg->id&subject=Re: " . stripcslashes( $msg->subject ), 'rwpm-reply_inbox_msg_' . $msg->id ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Reply', 'pm4wp' ); ?></a>
```

So I want to adjust the script so that it only adds **one** `Re:` if there is a reply. How do I do that? I am guessing maybe an IF statement checking if there is already a `Re:` there or not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, add the "Re: " only if there is no:

```
| <a class="reply" href="<?php echo wp_nonce_url( "?page=rwpm_send&recipient=$msg->sender&id=$msg->id&subject=".(strpos($msg->subject, "Re:") === false ? "Re: " : ""). stripcslashes( $msg->subject ), 'rwpm-reply_inbox_msg_' . $msg->id ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Reply', 'pm4wp' ); ?></a>
```

And, when it only should stay on the beginning:

```
   | <a class="reply" href="<?php echo wp_nonce_url( "?page=rwpm_send&recipient=$msg->sender&id=$msg->id&subject=".(substr($msg->subject, 0, 3) != "Re:" ? "Re: " : ""). stripcslashes( $msg->subject ), 'rwpm-reply_inbox_msg_' . $msg->id ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Reply', 'pm4wp' ); ?></a>
```

Comment: Well, I'm pessimist. What about a subject like "Blah BLAHRe: Blah blah". I feel like users tend to be really witty in terms of breaking code. Though your code can be fixed checking the pos is 0, I'd go for @lafor's regex, as it is cleaner.

Comment: @Blauesocke Can you kindly update your solution by checking that the pos is on 0?

Answer (score 2):

ow about a simple regexp?

```
$replysubject = preg_replace('/^(Re: )*/', 'Re: ', stripcslashes( $subject ));
```

This will output a string with just one 'Re: ' at the beginning, regardless of how many of them are in the input string.

In your case:

`href="<?php echo wp_nonce_url( "?page=rwpm_send&recipient=$msg->sender&id=$msg->id&subject=" . $replysubject, 'rwpm-reply_inbox_msg_' . $msg->id ); ?>"`

Comment: Can you please update your code by add your solution within my code and I will be able to add it to the script and make a test run.

Comment: Although I always tend to ease the work of the OP, it's just a matter of copy and paste, and read the regex. In fact, it is pretty straightforward and can help in your other stuff

Comment: I just tested this, it worked, however, it did not add the message title? Is there a typo in your code?